# Change from C++ to Python

Tags: python

Help me change from C ++ to Python with
Thanks everyone very much!

```
int main()
{
    int W; cout<< "Nhap tong khoi luong: "; cin >> W;
    int n; cout << "Nhap so do vat: "; cin>> n;
    int weight[100], worth[100];
    for(int i = 1; i<= n; i++)
    {
        cout<< "Nhap weight[" << i <<"]:"; cin >> weight[i];
        cout<< "Nhap worth[" << i <<"]:"; cin >> worth[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. in your C++ why not `for(int i = 0; i< n; i++)` this is not Fortran… Also why not `std::vector<int> weight(n), worth(n);` to be more dynamic. I did not quite get the use for `W` variable.

Answer (score 0):

C++ to python coming up:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write("Nhap tong khoi luong: ")
W=int(sys.stdin.readline())
sys.stdout.write("Nhap so do vat: ")
n=int(sys.stdin.readline())
weight=list()
worth=list()
for i in range(1,n+1):
    sys.stdout.write("Nhap weight["+str(i)+"]");
    weight.append(int(sys.stdin.readline()))
    sys.stdout.write("Nhap worth[" + str(i) + "]");
    worth.append(int(sys.stdin.readline()))
```